# Woocommerce: Hide Add To Cart Button if Customer has already purchased this Product

Tags: woocommerce

I would like to hide the Add-To-Cart-Button on the shop page if a Customer has already purchased this Product (in all his previous orders), in this case I'd like to dispay a notice in place of the button. I have found this Script [here](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-display-products-purchased-user/)

```
add_shortcode( 'my_purchased_products', 'bbloomer_products_bought_by_curr_user' );

function bbloomer_products_bought_by_curr_user() {

// GET CURR USER
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) return;

// GET USER ORDERS (COMPLETED + PROCESSING)
$customer_orders = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => $current_user->ID,
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_is_paid_statuses() ),
) );

// LOOP THROUGH ORDERS AND GET PRODUCT IDS
if ( ! $customer_orders ) return;
$product_ids = array();
foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order->ID );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $product_ids[] = $product_id;
    }
}
$product_ids = array_unique( $product_ids );
$product_ids_str = implode( ",", $product_ids );

// PASS PRODUCT IDS TO PRODUCTS SHORTCODE
return do_shortcode("[products ids='$product_ids_str']");
```

}

It works fine, it collects the previous products in $product_ids or $product_ids_str.

Now I'd like to use this in the loop, finding out for every product if its ID is part of the $product_ids Array. I have added the Shortcode [my_purchased_products] in the Shop page.

In the copied template files archive-product.php or content-product.php I'd like to use the $product_ids Array, or maybe the String $product_ids_str, so I changed the last line of the script from

```
return do_shortcode("[products ids='$product_ids_str']");
```

to

```
return $product_ids;
```

or

```
return $product_ids_str;
```

But although the script works fine I cannot access the results, var_dump() gives NULL.

Is there something wrong with the way I return $product_ids or $product_ids_str?
Or is there a better way to achieve the desired result?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I used finally [the built-in function `wc_customer_bought_product()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.4.1/includes/wc-user-functions.php#L301-L369) as follow:

```
$pid = get_the_ID(); 
$uid = get_current_user_id();

if( wc_customer_bought_product('', $uid, $pid ) )
    echo "already bought";
else
   echo "not bought yet";
```